# Convert number to decimal with tofixed function wrong

Tags: javascript, decimal, tofixed

I used the `tofixed()` function to convert 2 decimal places to 10 decimal places. The conversion turn out to be wrong.

My code is:

```
var decimal = parseFloat((343993110.92)).toFixed(10);
```

The result in Google Chrome is:

```
decimal = 343993110.9200000167
```

In Internet explorer the result of the conversion is correct.

**Question:** How do I get the expected result of `343993110.9200000000` in Google Chrome?

Comment: This is down to limitations in the `float` data type. What do you want to use the result for? If it's to show to the user, you could transform the value to a string and pad it.

Comment: @SimonBrahan The result used for calculation. I need to use 10 decimal places to calculate (sum the value with other numbers) the value accurately. And it is agreed between me and client to show the number in 10 decimal places.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)